# How can i edit the members of an abstract class

Tags: c++, class, vector, abstract-class

lets say that i have a vector

```
vector <Weapon*> W_List;
```

and those 3 classes

```
class Weapon {
protected:
    string name;
    int damage;
    int level;
public:
    Weapon() {

    }
    virtual void upgradeWeapon() {

    }
};

class Dagger : public Weapon {
public:
    Dagger(string _name){
        this-> name = _name;
        this-> damage = 30;
        this-> level = 1
    }
    void upgradeWeapon(int _dmg,int _lvl){
        this->damage = _dmg;
        this->level = _lvl;
    }
};

class Bow : public Weapon {
private:
        int range;
public:
        bow(string _name){
              this-> name = _name;
              this-> damage = 50;
              this-> level = 2
        void upgradeWeapon(int _dmg,int _lvl,int _range){
            this-> damage = _dmg;
            this-> level = _lvl;
            this-> range = _range;
        }
};

int main(int argc,char **argv) { 
    vector <Weapon*> W_List;
    if (argv[1] == "new"){
        if(argv[2] == "Dagger"){
            Dagger* dagger = new Dagger("argv[3]");
            W_List.push_back(dagger);
        }
        else if (argv[2] =="Bow"){
            Bow* bot = new Bow("argv[3]");  
            W_List.push_back(bow);
        }


     else if(argv[1] == "Upgrade"){
             //search in vector and upgrade the weapon
        }
}
```

So my question is if i give

> Upgrade "WeaponName" 70 4

How can i search in the vector for the name of the weapon and upgrade the attritubes of the spesific weapon?

Comment: Your class is not abstract.

Comment: You could use [`std::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find). More importantly, why all the `Weapon*`? Why not a `vector<Weapon>` instead?

Comment: If you definitely have to use pointers please use `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`

Comment: Just speculating here but the program probably wont work as intended by you: If you run your program again, all state is lost and reseted and as such the vector will be empty when passing `"Upgrade"` to it

Comment: BTW, you don't need to use `this->` syntax, unless you are differentiating parameters from members. (In this case, I would rename the member variables so they don't conflict.)

Comment: If `argv[1]` is `"Upgrade"` then `W_List` will be empty because the vector always starts empty and only gets elements if `argv[1]` is `"new"`. Maybe you are under the impression that `W_List` keeps its value between execution?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews You don't need to, but it does not cause harm. And some people like to use `this->` to help document that the identifier is a member. Personally, I like seeing it in questions. It reduces the cognitive burden of figuring out what all the identifiers are.

Comment: The signatures of `Dagger::upgradeWeapon()` and `Bow::upgradeWeapon()` do not match the signature of `Bow::upgradeWeapon()`, so you are not going to be able to call them via a `Weapon*` pointer, you would have to type-cast the pointer to the appropriate type first, which kind of defeats the purpose of making `Bow::upgradeWeapon()` virtual.

Comment: Since the derived `upgradeWeapon` functions have different arguments, they are not overrides to `Weapon::upgradeWeapon()`. There is no way to access them through a pointer to base. Even the data input will depend on the concrete type, because different weapons need different information to upgrade. Maybe consider having a `virtual` member function to receive input and perform the upgrade together instead of having a `virtual` member function to perform just the upgrade. The way upgrading is implemented, it is not usable in a polymorphic way.

Comment: Either that, or gather up the input values into an array first, and then pass the array to `Bow::upgradeWeapon()` and let concrete overrides decide how to use the values as needed.

Comment: Also note that comparisons like `argv[1] == "new"` won't ever work, because they actually compare only pointers (adresses) and won't compare the strings char by char. You need to use `strcmp` for that.

Comment: You have a design conflict. In `class Weapon`, you declare that code external to the class and its derived classes is to have no knowledge of the existence of a weapon's name (i.e. `name` is `protected` with no accessor functions). In your problem statement, you state that the `main` function (which is external to all class code) is supposed to know about a weapon's name. Which of these describes your intended design?